# wordpress: remove post excerpt on archive but keep thumbnail

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on [setting up my category archive to look more like a grid](http://www.theoddgirl.com/category/art/portfolio/) using custom css and have already successfully removed the elements I wanted to using, for example,

```
.archive .entry-footer {
    display: none;
}
```

So now I am left with post title and post summary. I would now like to remove the excerpt below the featured image thumbnail but in inspecting it with firebug, both sections seem to be labeled with .entry-summay. So if I use this code...

```
.archive .entry-summary {
    display: none;
}
```

it removes both the excerpt and image. Looking through what I can see on firebug and the stylesheet, I can't spot what to use to drill down the summary further to remove the excerpt and not the image. I thought to tell it to have a 0 character excerpt length in the archive if it wasn't as simple as removing the other elements but am not sure how that works via css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have a `.entry-summary` that wraps your image and your text, and another `.entry-summary` that wraps just the text (so one `.entry-summary` inside of the other).

To make it hide the text, you could target the inner `.entry-summary` like this:

```
.archive .entry-summary .entry-summary {
    display: none;
}
```

Although, if you want to hide the text, you may want to consider editing the template in a child-theme so that it doesn't even exist on the page.

Comment: Thanks! that totally explains why both were labeled like that, how weird though. It totally worked.